# Retrieve user phone number from phone book using alexa skills or ask

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch phone number for a particular contact from phone book using AWS alexa skills or ask. This could be similar to voice calling feature between alexa to alexa. Can anyone help me with this.